# What is the combinatorial proof for the formula of $S(n,k)$ - Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

What is the combinatorial proof for the formula of Stirling numbers of the second kind ?

$${n\brace k}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}jj^n$$

where ${n\brace k} = S\left(n,k\right)$ is the number of set partitions of a fixed $n$-element set into $k$ parts.

Comment: Take a look at these [notes](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/stml-65-prev.pdf), section 7.3. The alternating sum should immediately invite you to think of an inclusion/exclusion argument.

Answer (score 3):

Count non-surjective functions $[n]\to [k]$. Use inclusion-exclusion by counting functions $A_i$ that miss one particular element $i\in [k]$ and then consider $A_1\cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_k$.