# How many different clusterings are possible for certain number of clusters and elements

Tags: combinatorics, clustering

let $C = \{C_1,... ,C_2 \}$ be a clustering of $k$ Clusters and I have a set $G$ with $n$ objects in total. Then I want to find different clusterings which meet the basic condition of a clustering:
 $C_j \subset G$ and $C_i \cap C_j$ for $i \neq j$ and $G = \cup_{i=1}^{k} C_i$.

My script than states without proof that the number of possible clusterings C with k Clusters and n elements is given by

$$
s(k,n) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{k-j} \binom{k}{j}j^n
$$

I couldn't find that formular by googling and I wanted to know how this formula is derived (at least heuristically), since the term $(-1)^{k-j}$ is really counter-intuitive for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Hint:** The numbers ${n\brace k}$ or $S(n,k)$ are called *[Stirling numbers of the Second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* and give the number of subdivisions of a set of $n$ objects into $k$ partitions.
>
> The expression 
>   $${n\brace k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{k-j} \binom{k}{j}j^n
> $$
>   is one *[explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula)* for the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

*Notes:*

- The factor $(-1)^{k-j}$ often indicates an application of the *[Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*.
- A short combinatorial answer is stated in *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339124/what-is-the-combinatorial-proof-for-the-formula-of-sn-k-stirling-numbers-of)*.
- The symbol $s(n,k)$ or $\left[n\atop k\right]$ is usually reserved for the *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)*.